# Laravel: Return a value from App::call()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm going on a limb here; I'm trying to direct a long running script to Artisan. Is it possible for `App::call()` to return a string value or maybe even send an email once the long running script finishes?

I'm trying to look for more info on this, but is it right to assume that if Artisan is running I can redirect the user to something like a waiting page, maybe a looping gif?

Comment: Is my answer enough detail for you, or do you need more direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Queue::push()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues) with an appropriate driver (database, perhaps) to push the long-running job to a queue.

The last thing the long-running job should do is send some indication that it's finished.

Here's some sample code:

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($id)
{
    Artisan::call('my-command', ['arg1', 'arg2']);

    $job->delete();
});

// Then at the end of your my-command script:
$jobModel = LongRunningJob::find($id);
$jobModel->finishedDate = Carbon::now();
$jobModel->save();
```

Of course you can then poll the database to determine whether the long-running command has finished.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a sample using this in action?

Comment: Not public, no -- what part of it would you like explained more fully?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ben. I'm trying to see how I can redirect to a "preloading" page while the long script works its way. I can't seem to make ends meet. It's like when the long script is triggered (around 5 - 30 mins duration), a `redirect()` is called with a looping gif, and once it's complete a success page can be redirected to. Am I making sense somehow?

Comment: Sure -- but that's a very odd scenario. Normally for a 5-30 minute script, I wouldn't leave a browser session connected; I would use AJAX to poll every minute to check whether the script had finished, and if so display an indication to the user. If you really want to notify the browser instantly on script finish, you'd need to use a websocket, which is outside my expertise.